# How to make Python scripts available anywhere in PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, path

Currently working with Python in WIndows 10.

I am trying to setup PowerShell so that Python would find scripts even if I am currently in different folder. Simply speaking, I would like to run script as follows

```
python myscript.py
```

instead of

```
python D:\aaa\bbb\myscript.py
```

I have only tried to append the extra folders to environment variable `Path` in PowerShell

```
$Env:Path = $Env:Path + ';D:\aaa\bbb'
```

and the script can be found itself, such as I can use TAB to autocomplete a script name, however python still does not recognise the file, that is `python myscript.py` still returns `[Error] No such file as myscript.py`.

Is there any environment variable that controls locations where script are searched? `PYTHONPATH` seems to be for imported modules inside Python interpreter.

Comment: No, there is no facility for that in Powershell or in Python.

Comment: @tripleee Cheers! I know in Linux one can insert the line `#!/usr/bin/env python` and let the script invoke a program to run the script itself. I guess this is neither possible in PowerShell, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `D:\aaa\bbb` directory is in the `PATH` variable and `.py` is in the `PATHEXT` variable, then you could use:

```
(Get-Command -Name myscript.py).Source
```